# Why is 'What is the difference between slice, segment and leg" on-topic while "What are the definitions of stages/sequences" was closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why is [What is the difference between slice, segment and leg?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14567/1400) on-topic while  [What are the definitions of stages and sequences when describing a flight, and how do they compare against leg/portion/sector/segment? [closed]](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/87689/1400) was closed as off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

As is so often the case in these sort of meta-questions ("Why is X on topic but Y not?") you're comparing a *very* old question (left open, possibly on topic in it's day) to a very new question (closed, as currently not in scope).

If the open question were asked today, I would expect it to be closed for the same reason the now closed one is; our scope has moved on, and questions about the "passenger aspects" of aviation are specifically [off-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks, np that's fine, just making sure the recent closure was aligned with the website's current scope.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a policy of closing old questions that are no longer on topic, so that they don't receive any new answers, and don't provide bad examples for the future?

Comment: @RayButterworth in an ideal world, when a off-topic policy changes we would go back and find every question now off topic and close it. That's just not realistic in the real world.